# reactjs stop propagation, call another function to setState

Tags: reactjs, preventdefault, stoppropagation, event-propagation

I have an Onclick attached to the whole component, wherever clicked it closes the component:

```
   <div className="container" onClick={this.onClick.bind(this,'str')}>
            {this.state.showtoggle ? <Child2 /> : <Child1 />}
          </div>
```

But inside the child2 component, I do not want the whole component should be clickable.
1) Can I attach the click handler just to Child1 - with this conditional logic in place
2) Or I am trying to stopPropagation in child2 - but the state is not getting updated as expected after preventDefault...any idea?

Code inside CHild2:

```
 handleClick(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if(event.target.name === 'b2'){
          this.setState({
        toggleClassname: 'b2',
    });
    }
  } 

<button name="b1" onClick={this.handleClick} className={`btn-element ${(this.state.toggleClassname === 'b1') ? 'red' : ''}`}>button1</button>

<button name="b2" onClick={this.handleClick} className={`btn-element ${(this.state.toggleClassname === 'b2') ? 'red' : ''}`}>button2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass `onClick` to Child1, and then attach it to the button in Child 1.

```
var onClick = this.onClick.bind(this,'str');
<div className="container">
        {this.state.showtoggle ? <Child2 onClick={onClick} /> : <Child1 onClick={onClick} />}
      </div>
```

Child1:

```
class Child1 extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onClick: React.PropTypes.func
  }

  render() {
    return <button name="b1" onClick={this.props.onClick}>button1</button>
  }
}
```

Child2:

```
class Child2 extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onClick: React.PropTypes.func
  }

  render() {
    return <div><img onClick={this.props.onClick}/></div>
  }
}
```

Essentially you are just having to manually reimplement `onClick` for your custom component, which is a bit confusing.

Comment: I still need this onclick handler in <Child2> but not on the whole component just on an image click inside Child2, but on whole child1..?how do I accomplish this?

Comment: Updated the answer, basically just do the same thing for both components, placing the click handler where it is needed.